# PostgreSQL , to_char function

Tags: sql, postgresql, to-char

I have this number 0101110 but i need only 5 digits. for exemple (01110)

i used this
select to_char(trim('0101110')::int,'99999V')
but PG returns #####

if someone can help me , thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to get the 5 right characters ?

Comment: you can do it using an arithmetique operations or string manipulation as: `select substring ( cast(0101110 as text) from char_length(cast(0101110 as text)) - 5);`

Comment: To make this a proper question please provide the *data type* of the number and your version of Postgres.

Comment: nice man, but for this case , i dont need to use char_lengh, i used this
select substr('0110110', 3) as as_cod
and the output is only 10110 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you have a number that starts with a zero?  I suspect your "number" is really being stored as a string.

If so, just use `right()` to take the rightmost five characters:

```
select right(col, 5)
```

If the value is really stored as a number, then convert it to a string first.

Comment: Yeah, i putted the number 0101110, but i have a column varchar 7 that numbers starts with 01????? and 00?????, the problem is the number with 01. thanks for help.... but i solved with this line 
select substr('0110110', 3) as as_cod